# VS2013 Database Project using SQL CLR - unresolved reference to object [servername\username] (the Database Owner)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlclr

I am working on a Database project in VS2013 that contains a C# SQL CLR stored procedure.

The assembly owner is [servername\User123]
The database owner is also [servername\User123]  (Being the database owner, this user obviously already exists on the server.  I managed a successful publish of the database by commenting out the code in my SQL CLR procedure and publishing, the following occurs after I un-comment-out that code.)

If I try to **build** the project in VS, I get the error:

```
Error   1   SQL71501: Assembly: [DatabaseProject] has an unresolved reference to object [servername\User123].
```

...caused by:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [DatabaseProject] AUTHORIZATION [servername\User123]
FROM 0x4D5A90000300000004000000FFFF0000B8000etcetcetcetc
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
GO
```

So, if in VS I add a create user script in the \Security folder:

```
CREATE USER [servername\User123] FOR LOGIN [servername\User123] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO
GRANT CONNECT TO [servername\User123]
```

Then I can **build** the project.

However, if I then try to **Publish** the database, I get the error:

```
Creating [servername\User123]...
(47,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The login already has an account under a different user name.
(47,0): SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE USER [servername\User123] FOR LOGIN [servername\User123];
An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
```

Is there a "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to a simple misunderstanding of how SQL Server handles the "owner" of the database as a database "principal". The concept of "database owner" shows up in two different ways:

1. As a database-level **User** having the name of `dbo` and a `principal_id` of `1`. Now, what server-level **Login** maps to this particular **User** (i.e. "principal") is simply a matter of the value in the `SID` field in `sys.database_principals`:

   ```sql
   SELECT sdp.*
   FROM   [sys].[database_principals] sdp
   WHERE  sdp.[principal_id] = 1;
   ```

   This field will map to the `SID` field in `sys.server_principals`:

   ```sql
   SELECT sdp.*, '---' AS [---], ssp.*
   FROM   [sys].[database_principals] sdp
   INNER JOIN [sys].[server_principals] ssp
           ON ssp.[sid] = sdp.[sid]
   WHERE  sdp.[principal_id] = 1;
   ```

   Pay attention to the following fields in `sys.database_principals`:

   - type
   - type_desc
   - authentication_type
   - authentication_type_desc

   Seeing as how your database is currently owned by a Windows Login, run the query immediately above (the 2nd query--the one with both tables). Next, change the database to be owned by `sa`. Next, open up a NEW query tab. Finally, run the same query in this new window (so that you can easily compare the "before" and "after" results), making sure to pay close attention to the 4 fields noted above, as well as the `sid` field. (*Please note that it is possible to create **User**s without **Login**s and those will not show up, obviously, in a query that JOINs to `sys.server_principals`, but this question is dealing specifically with **Login**s*).

   From all of this you should see that specifying a **Login** to be the "owner" of a database does *not*, in fact, create a **User** for that **Login**: it merely updates the definition of the `dbo` **User**. Hence, the **Login** that owns the database does *technically* exist in that database, but always with the name of `dbo` instead of its actual name. This is why you are getting the following error:

   > The login already has an account under a different user name.
2. As a **Database Role** that any **User** in the database can be added to in order to be given those permissions.

To fix:

- Remove your `CREATE USER` script from the **\Security** folder.
- Use `AUTHORIZATION [dbo]` instead.